# GetType.Equals(typeof(Type)) return false in .Net Core but not in .Net Framework

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0

Ola, 
just migrated to .Net Core and Type.Equals seem to return false even though the types are equal.

The debugger gives the following info:

## The First Instance:

**typeof(ExcelImportLoaderConfig):** {Name = "ExcelImportLoaderConfig" FullName = "DatenMeister.Excel.Helper.ExcelImportLoaderConfig"}

**typeof(ExcelImportLoaderConfig).Assembly** {DatenMeister.Excel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}

**typeof(ExcelImportLoaderConfig).Assembly.Location**
"...\netcoreapp3.0\DatenMeister.Excel.dll" - same path

## The Second Instance:

**configuration.GetType()** {Name = "ExcelImportLoaderConfig" FullName = "DatenMeister.Excel.Helper.ExcelImportLoaderConfig"}

**configuration.GetType().Assembly** {DatenMeister.Excel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}

**configuration.GetType().Assembly.Location** "...\netcoreapp3.0\DatenMeister.Excel.dll" - same path

## The Comparison

(configuration is ExcelImportLoaderConfig): false
**THIS WAS TRUE IN .NET FRAMEWORK** and is now false in .Net Core 3.0

Is there a change between .Net Framework and .Net Core?

### [EDIT]:

m_cache and m_handle are different between (configuration.GetType() and typeof(ExcelImportLoaderConfig))...

MetadataToken is the same...

Further Information:

- configuration is created via 'configuration = new ExcelImportLoaderConfig(); (with reference to the .Net Standard assembly below)
- typeof(ExcelImportLoaderConfig) is called within a .Net Standard assembly

### [EDIT 2]

Same problem with .Net Core 3.1

.dll creating the instance of ExcelImportLoaderConfig is a .Net Standard 2.0 (netstandard2.0) .dll

The .dll checking the instance is also a .Net Standard 2.0 which also contains the declaration of ExcelImportLoaderConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The file was referenced in the main project but the type was not used.

There is a PluginLoader which loads all assemblies via 'Assembly.LoadFile' within the directory.

So, this happened:

1. The PluginLoader loads the Assembly directly via Assembly.LoadFile. The check now included the type checking of to the explicitly loaded assembly. #1
2. Later, within the application, a function uses the referenced assembly which uses the reference assembly (even though, it has the file). But internally, the assembly seems to be loaded twice. #2
3. The application creates an instance of the class via #2 and calls a function within the explicitly loaded assembly #1. ExcelImportLoaderConfig, loaded via Assembly.LoadFile #1, is not the same as loaded via ProjectReference #2...

This behavior is different between .Net Core and .Net Framework

Comment: It is not different.  Never use LoadFile(), only LoadFrom().

Answer (score 0):

Further information given under

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36787

> Assembly Loading via ProjectReference and Assembly.LoadFile upon same file leads to two instances #36787